# My docker container keeps instantly closing when trying to run an image for bigcode-tools

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker, and I'm not sure how to quite deal with this situation.

So I'm trying to run a docker container in order to replicate some results from a research paper, specifically from here: https://github.com/danhper/bigcode-tools/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md
(image link: https://hub.docker.com/r/tuvistavie/bigcode-tools/).

I'm using a windows machine, and every time I try to run the docker image (via: docker run -p 80:80 tuvistavie/bigcode-tools), it instantly closes. I've tried running other images, such as the getting-started, but that image doesn't close instantly.

I've looked at some other potential workarounds, like using -dit, but since the instructions require setting an alias/doskey for a docker run command, using the alias and chaining it with other commands multiple times results in creating a queue for the docker container since the port is tied to the alias.

Like in the instructions from the GitHub link, I'm trying to set an alias/doskey to make api calls to pull data, but I am unable to get any data nor am I getting any errors when performing the calls on the command prompt.

Sorry for the long question, and thank you for your time!

Going in order of the instructions:
0. I can run this, it added the image to my Docker Desktop
1.

- Since I'm using a windows machine, I had to use 'set' instead of 'export'
- I'm not exactly sure what the $ is meant for in UNIX, and whether or not it has significant meaning, but from my understanding, the whole purpose is to create a directory named 'bigcode-workspace'
- Instead of 'alias,' I needed to use doskey.

2. 

- Since -dit prevented my image from instantly closing, I added that in as well, but I'm not 100% sure what it means. Running docker run (...) resulted in the docker image instantly closing.
- When it came to using the doskey alias + another command, I've tried:

- (doskey macro) (another command)
- (doskey macro) ^& (another command)
- (doskey macro) $T (another command)

- This also seemed to be using github api call, so I also added a --token=(github_token), but that didn't change anything either
- Because the later steps require expected data pulled from here, I am unable to progress any further.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this image is designed to be used as a command-line utility. So it should not be running continuously, but you run it via alias `docker-bigcode` for your tasks.

`$BIGCODE_WORKSPACE` is an environment variable expansion here. So on a Windows machine it's `%BIGCODE_WORKSPACE%`. You might want to set this variable in `Settings->System->About->Advanced System Settings`, because variables set with `SET` command will apply to the current command prompt session only. Or you can  specify the path directly, without environment variable.

As for alias then I would just create a batch file with the following content:

```powershell
docker run -p 6006:6006 -v %BIGCODE_WORKSPACE%:/bigcode-tools/workspace tuvistavie/bigcode-tools %*
```

This will run the specified command appending the batch file parameters at the end. You might need to add double quotes if `BIGCODE_WORKSPACE` path contains spaces.

Comment: Hi Mike, what does the %* represent at the end of the alias?

Comment: It means all the command line arguments passed to the batch file will be appended at this place.